# No injection between the power set of a set A and the set A.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

For finite sets it's easy to prove it because the cardinal of the power set it's bigger than that of the set so there won't be enough elements in the codomain for the function to be injective. What is the proof for infinte sets though?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need the famous cantor diagonalization argument http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_diagonal_argument

Comment: [Let me google that for you](http://bit.ly/1xoKcYK).

Answer (score 0):

Assume $f:  A\to \Bbb P(A)$ is a bijection. Look at the subset $B\subseteq A$ given as
$$
b\in B \leftrightarrow b \notin f(b)
$$
By construction we have both $f^{-1}(B)\in B$ and $f^{-1}(B)\notin B$.